# What is the difference between AWS ASG cooldown period and the warmup period in the scaling policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

What is the difference between AWS ASG cooldown period (which I can edit when I want to update my autoscaling group) and the warmup period in the scaling policy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

cooldowns prevent runaway scaling events. If your system is running high on CPU and your auto scaling rule adds an instance, it is going to take 5 minutes or so before the instance is fully spun up and helping with the load. Without a cooldown, the rule would keep firing and might add 4 or 5 instances before the CPU metrics came down, resulting in wasteful over-provisioning. Or in the scale down case, overshoot and result in under-provisioning.

[image]

> with a cooldown period in place, the Auto Scaling group launches an
> instance and then suspends scaling activities due to simple scaling
> policies or manual scaling until the specified time elapses. (The
> default is 300 seconds.) This gives newly launched instances time to
> start handling application traffic. After the cooldown period expires,
> any suspended scaling actions resume. If the CloudWatch alarm fires
> again, the Auto Scaling group launches another instance, and the
> cooldown period takes effect again. If, however, the additional
> instance was enough to bring the CPU utilization back down, then the
> group remains at its current size.

[Cooldown](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html)

**Instance Warmup**

Warm-up value for Instances allows you to control the time until a newly launched instance can contribute to the CloudWatch metrics, so when warm-up time has expired, an instance is considered to be a part Auto Scaling group and will receive traffic.

> With step scaling policies, you can specify the number of seconds that
> it takes for a newly launched instance to warm up. Until its specified
> warm-up time has expired, an instance is not counted toward the
> aggregated metrics of the Auto Scaling group. While scaling out, AWS
> also does not consider instances that are warming up as part of the
> current capacity of the group. Therefore, multiple alarm breaches that
> fall in the range of the same step adjustment result in a single
> scaling activity. This ensures that we don't add more instances than
> you need.

[as-scaling-target-tracking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html)

Answer (score 3):

I determined two key differences and one observation of warm-up:

- warm-up applies only to scale out
- cooldown applies to both scale in and scale out
- warm-up applies to all scaling policies
- cooldown applies **only** to [simple scaling policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html)
- [warm-up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html#as-step-scaling-warmup) of a step-scaling policy only inhibits scale out of the number of instances it follows on from

  - Scaling according to the first step, from 10->11 will trigger a warm up period
  - During this period metrics within the first range can be ignored entirely
  - A metric in a second step, say adding 3 instances, will only trigger adding 3-1 = 2 instances instead, whilst warm-up is in effect

Comment: For the third bullet, warm-up applies to step and target tracking scaling policies (not simple).

Comment: So they are really completely exclusive? They do kinda similar controls, but you never have both at the same time.